# send email with url image

Tags: php, image, email, send

i am including a path to an image like this:

```
$msg.='<img src="http://my.test.ca/images/show.jpg" width="75" height="75" />'
```

in my sendmail function.

the path works and the image is in the specified folder.

here is what happens to the image src when i get the email:

http://my.test.ca/images/sh%20w.jpg

it sorts of breaks the image. any ideas why.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using this "(" bracket to open and close your image tags?

Comment: i used ( for posting to this forum. as when i use < it doesnt show it on stackoverflow.

Comment: In a code block they do. In "normal" text you have to use &lt; and &gt;

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, there is an space in the image name:

```
sho w.jpg
```

instead of:

```
show.jpg
```

**%20** means space which is auto-detected. So, make sure that there is no space in the file name.

Also i wonder why you are not using the <> tags when specifying image?

```
$msg.='(img src="http://my.test.ca/images/show.jpg" width="75" height="75" /);
```

Instead of:

```
$msg.='<img src="http://my.test.ca/images/show.jpg" width="75" height="75" />;
```

Comment: there is no space as i rename the image in photoshop for that reason and visited the url to make sure its there.

Answer (score 0):

Is the string written properly? With a single quote and a semi-colon at the end?

```
$msg .= '(img src="http://my.test.ca/images/show.jpg" width="75" height="75" /)';
```

**Update** 
**Try :**

```
$msg .= '<img src="http://my.test.ca/images/show.jpg" width="75" height="75">';
```

Comment: yes, its written properly. i even rename the image in photoshop. hmm